# Do React child components always need to be stateful?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When a child component's sole purpose is to consume its parent's state, does it need to be stateful itself?

Looking at these two examples:

**"Stateless"**

```
const ServicesCard = ({ service, onClick, isPro = false }) => {
  const name = isPro && service.pro?._id ? service.pro.pro_name : service.name;
  let price = isPro && service.pro?._id ? service.pro.total : service.total;

  // Special case scenarios
  let prefix;
  let suffix;

  if (service.hasPages) {
    prefix = 'from';
  }
  if (service.uid === 'abcdef') {
    prefix = '';
    price = `${price} per page`;
    suffix = '($5 minimum)';
  }
  if (service.uid === 'qwerty') {
    suffix = "+ gov't fees";
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.servicesCard} onClick={onClick}>
      <h1 className={styles.header}>{name}</h1>
      <p className={styles.pricing}>
        <span className={styles.prefix}>{prefix}</span>
        <span className={styles.price}>{`$${price}`}</span>
        <span className={styles.suffix}>{suffix}</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Stateful**

```
const ServicesCard = ({ service, onClick, isPro = false }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [price, setPrice] = useState('');
  const [prefix, setPrefix] = useState('');
  const [suffix, setSuffix] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const _name = isPro && service.pro?._id ? service.pro.pro_name : service.name;
    let _price = isPro && service.pro?._id ? service.pro.total : service.total;

    // Special case scenarios
    let _prefix;
    let _suffix;

    if (service.hasPages) {
      _prefix = 'from';
    }
    if (service.uid === 'abcdef') {
      _prefix = '';
      _price = `${_price} per page`;
      _suffix = '($5 minimum)';
    }
    if (service.uid === 'qwerty') {
      _suffix = "+ gov't fees";
    }

    setName(_name)
    setPrice(_price)
    setPrefix(_prefix)
    setSuffix(_suffix)
  }, [service]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.servicesCard} onClick={onClick}>
      <h1 className={styles.header}>{name}</h1>
      <p className={styles.pricing}>
        <span className={styles.prefix}>{prefix}</span>
        <span className={styles.price}>{`$${price}`}</span>
        <span className={styles.suffix}>{suffix}</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I feel like both of them would behave the same, since a re-render will be triggered by a state change higher up in the tree anyways, forcing everything to be recalculated. React also emphasizes that [Data flows down](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down).

Provided that `service` is the only prop that changes, why should I use more browser memory by using the `useState` & `useEffect` React APIs?

Comment: No, stateless components are fine. The general guideline previously was to make as much of your code base stateless as possible.

Comment: You JSX doesn't update the state in that second example, it just uses the `onClick` handler passed into it, so using state in that component is fairly meaningless.

Comment: On top of @Andy's comment, it is actually considered anti-pattern in React to store passed props into local component state, just consume the props directly in children components. To answer base question "Do React child components always need to be stateful?" - well, no, they only need state when they need state, i.e. when it makes sense for them to "own" some state locally.